# Prove by induction for$ P(x)$

Tags: induction

$P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$,with $a_n\neq 0$. Using induction on $n$, prove that $P^{(n)}(x) = n!a_n$.
So I start with $n=1$ but $P(x) =a_1x$ and $P^{(1)}(x)=1a_1$ are not equal because of the $x$. What do I do with the $x$? Do I have to induce twice?

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
\begin{align*}
P_0^{(0)}(x) &= P_0(x) = a_0 = 0!a_0 \\
P_1^{(1)}(x) &= P_1'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}[a_1x + a_0] = a_1 = 1!a_1 \\
P_2^{(2)}(x) &= P_2''(x) = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}[a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0] = 2a_2 = 2!a_2 \\
&~~\vdots
\end{align*}

Comment: What happens to the x when you take the derivative in the last one?

Comment: We took the derivative twice:
$$
a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0 \to 2a_2x + a_1 \to 2a_2
$$

Comment: Ok I get that now. But how do I show P<sup>n-1</sup>(x)?

Comment: Start with $P_n(x)$ and find its first derivative. You'll get a polynomial of degree $n - 1$, so you can apply the induction hypothesis to get what you want.